# Get the way point of the stop over between two points distance matrix API

Tags: php, jquery, google-distancematrix-api

I am using the distance matrix API and its working fine when I am finding  the distance between 2 points starting and arrival .

I want to calculate the distance for a stop point like a distance between a start and end point .

like A and B are the distance between the end and start point and C is a place between A and B how can I get the distance between two using this API in PHP . Please advice

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

Distance Matrix API does not currently support getting the distance in a stop point between two locations (origin and destination). As a workaround, you can use **[Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints)** in **Directions API** web service which returns a route that includes pass throughs or stopovers at intermediate locations. Through the returned routes you can get the distance for the waypoint.

Sample request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

The response should contain something like this with the distance between the origin address to the first waypoint address:

```
{
    .....

    legs: [
            {
                distance: {
                    text: "1.8 mi",
                    value: 2856
                },
                duration: {
                    text: "10 mins",
                    value: 582
                },
                end_address: "Charlestown, Boston, MA, USA",
                end_location: {
                    lat: 42.3781732,
                    lng: -71.06024889999999
                },
                start_address: "Boston, MA, USA",
                start_location: {
                    lat: 42.3598127,
                    lng: -71.0598527
                }
             ......
             }
           ]
     .....
}
```

If you will be using client-side Maps JavaScript Directions Service. Refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) and [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints).

Hope this helps!